# getting pixel dimensions of react flexbox child?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have an react app that uses maps a lot, and for them to render properly I need to pass in "hard" width and height in pixels.  I have its container as a flexbox so its dimensions vary at render depending on device, orientation etc.

So the question is - how to find out the computed width and height of the container box at runtime so I can pass that along to the inner map?

For example:

```
<Column className="no-pad">
   <WalkingMap 
       isShowing={true} 
       height={this.state.mapHeight}   <-- want to pass this
       width={this.state.mapWidth}     <-- and this
   />
   <there is another sibling 'overlay' component here too>
</Column>
```

Can I just grab the "getElementbyId" or is that frowned upon in react world?  I have tried libs like 'react-container-dimensions' but that only accepts a single child, and I will have two children because one is an overlay.  The Column component is not really always a column, more a flexbox that adjusts itself.  I've tried React.createRef but couldn't get it to work on the flexbox - it always comes back undefined.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with the `ref` callback.

```js
class App extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.myElement = null;
    }

    render(){
        return <div className="container">
            <div className="child" ref={ e => this.myElement = e }>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }

}
```

This is an extremely simplified example of two flex elements and the window resize event updating the state with the width and height of one of the DOM elements:

https://codepen.io/rhernando/pen/caa3b5fc148590c345fd6f9b06c85437?editors=0110

If it doesn't answer your question, please provide more concise info about your scenario and perhaps a reduced live sample.

---

**EDIT**

Based on your codepen sample there are two options.

One is to use HOC and use your parent with ref forwarding:

https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Two, is to use this code:

```js
class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="child">
        <h4>Here's my dimensions</h4>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.props, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      width: 0, height: 0
    };
    this.container = null;
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    window.onresize = () => {
            this.setState({
                width: this.container.clientWidth,
                height: this.container.clientHeight,
            });
        };
    this.setState({
      width: this.container.clientWidth,
      height: this.container.clientHeight,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { width, height } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="parent" ref={ e => this.container = e }>
        <Child dimensions={{width, height}} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
      <div className="container">
        <Parent />
        </div>
    );
    }
}
```

Basically use your child component in your parent render method, unless you must pass it as a prop to the parent, and then pass the parent dimensions (those are the ones you're interested in) to the child component. This code doesn't have more side effects than the one using the child component as a prop of the parent, since the updates are the same.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo for helping me.  I looked at your codepen and I tried it in my code.   I still get undefined as to the dimensions of the container.  I thought it might be a timing thing, but even when i tried a setTimeout to grab the dimensions, it comes back undefined.  I noticed in your codepen it also doesn't get the initial value but only gets it on a resize?

Comment: Perhaps you could try to see what you're getting from the DOM element. It seems that whatever you're pointing to is `undefined`, hence the error you're getting. Please update your code or add a response with that part of your code. Also I've updated the codepen to get the dimensions on start.

Comment: Ok I've created a codepen.  I think it has something to do with the fact that all my elements are other React components.  See here.
https://codepen.io/terrycoco/pen/pZVLmr?editors=1111